# Record Types Design Structure

Tags: record-type, design-patterns

I currently have a couple of thousands Contacts in my org.
 After a long discussion we decided that it would work towards our benefit if we could segment the Contacts into 2 segments:

**a)** Consultants **b)** Clients.

After some research I found out that having 2 record types for the Contact SObject could be the best design approach in potentially tackling this problem.

However all the current existing Contacts would need to go the Clients Type while Consultants would be added later on.

My questions are:

- **1)** Is there a way I could reallocate all the contacts to belong to
  the Client  type?
- **2)** Do I have to recreate all the contact fields
  for the new record type?
- **3)** If all the contacts would go to either
  one of the 2 record types, what would happen to the original contact
  Object, should I set it to be the master type?
- **4)** If I want to create a new Contact record of Client type using the API,    would there be an additional step I'd need to specify, more exactly how would I choose the record type.
- **5)** How easy is to change a record of type Consultant to a record of type Client?

I rather feel confused in understanding what would be best approach? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@marc, recordtype is nothing but just to differentiate your records. It will never effect your current records.

> 1. Is there a way I could reallocate all the contacts to belong to the Client type?
>
>    - Just need to do a bulk update using dataloader or any other tool.
> 2. Do I have to recreate all the contact fields for the new record type?
>
>    - No
> 3. If all the contacts would go to either one of the 2 record types, what would happen to the original contact objct, should I set it to be the master type?
>
>    - No change will happen to your current contact. It will be same as it is now.
> 4. If I want to create a new Contact record of Client type using the api, would there be an additional step I'd need to specify, more exactly how would I choose the record type.
>
>    - If you mean that you need to create a record from an external system. Then you need to specify the record type and handle it in salesforce using apex or workflow. If you are looking for creating a record from salesforce UI then you just need to add the recordtype to your profile so that before creating a contact it will ask to choose a record type.
> 5. How easy is to change a record of type Consultant to a record of type Client?
>
>    - You just need to to go to UI and change manually or you can do a bulk update using dataloader.

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

My questions are:

1) Is there a way I could reallocate all the contacts to belong to the Client type?

> Yes you need to bulk update their recordType and assign them client
>   record type.

2) Do I have to recreate all the contact fields for the new record type?

> No. You can't need to create any fields. All fields are available.

3) If all the contacts would go to either one of the 2 record types, what would happen to the original contact objct, should I set it to be the master type?

> It will not affect original contact object. only difference is now they have record type field is available and one of the record type need to be selected by default.

Also If you are not sure about record type then you can create a picklist field with both value and can differentiate your contact based on that.

Comment: thanks for your response, I added another question in the mean time.  So for example in a SQOL query if I don't specify the record type of the object it will get all the default one? Will same thing happen If I want to create a new Contact record using the api?

Comment: @MarcZaharescu if you don't supply recordType Id in filter then it will give you all records. If you create new record then you need to select one record type first.

Answer (score 1):

After you have created the two record types (Client and Consultant), every existing Contact actually has the Master record type (which appears as empty when you edit a Contact record).

1. If you want to set all existing Contacts to the Client record type, there are many possible ways to do that: a) Manually set the record type for each record (not recommended), b) Use an ETL tool (such as Apex Data Loader) to extract record details and update the record type, c) Write some Apex code to do that (needs development skills).
2. All existing standard and custom fields of the Contact SObject will be available to use with the new record types, so there is no need to do anything else.
3. When you create a new Contact record, Salesforce will let you choose between one of the two record types you have created. Actually you don't have to worry about anything else. The only additional thing you should do is create page layouts and link each record type to a page layout.

Record types is a feature of the Enterprise edition.

Comment: thanks for the answer I added 2 more questions in the mean time.